# SAS proc tabulate questions

Tags: sas, proc

My dataset looks like this:

```
 ID Var1    Var2    Var3
 A    1      0       1
 B    0      0       1
 B    1      1       0
 A    0      0       0
 A    1      1       1
```

My expected output will be:

```
    ID  Var1    Var2    Var3
    A   2        1       3
    B   1        1       1
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not access to SAS right now but try the following:-

```
proc tabulate data = in;
  class id;
  var var:;
  table id, sum=''*(var1 var2 var3);
run;
```

Comment: Sounds good to me.  I'd change the table statement slightly to make it fit the 'box' properly: 
`table id=' ', sum=''*(var1 var2 var3)/box='ID';`